# MariaDB refusing remote connections

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am currently using digitalocean ubuntu 16.04 . I am new to this version because I used older versions before.

I have a problem in connecting to the database remotely but when I logged in to the phpmyadmin it is all ok.

by the way I followed the tutorial in this article by Dan Costinel

https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

Find this line in file

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Change the IP address to you server IP adress

Example:

```
bind-address = 101.10.14.16
```

And the just restart the service

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Also you might have to open the firewall ports if you have UFW firewall enabled

take a look at this article that talk about this in detail

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-5-—-allowing-other-connections

Comment: cd /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ is unknown. Thank you but I fixed it already. I found the cnf. at /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf